# Xamarin.Forms detect empty ListView with ReactiveUI to show Label

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I would like to show a label when a ListView is empty. I tried several things, for example:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Items, (a) => a.Any())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsVisible, out _isVisible)
```

Where "Items" is the Reactive list of items: ReactiveList Items
And "IsVisible" the binded property to the label IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" attribute.

The problem is, that its not updating when the "Items" changed from empty to not empty or reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching your `Items` property will not cause the `WhenAnyValue` to fire if you're only adding or removing items from the list.  It will fire when the `Items` property itself changes.

What it sounds like you're looking for is a notification when the actual count of the items in the list changes.  Something like:

```
Items.CountChanged
    .Select(count => count == 0)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsVisible, out _isVisible);
```

**Edit**
This assumes that your `IsVisible` property is set up like:

```
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isVisible;
public bool IsVisible => _isVisible.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. The "out" keyword cant be added. For the is visible property i have the following code. This don't change when I add items to the list..

bool _isVisible;

public bool IsVisible
        {
            get => _isVisible;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isVisible, value);
        }

Comment: The Items property looks like this:

public ReactiveList<IGroup> Items
        {
            get => _items;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _items, value);
        }